# How can I get video duration from raw video file in React?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

My need is to get the **duration** OR time length of this video file. So I did  `console.log(videoFile.duration)` but its show **`undefined`** & why does it show undefined?  So how can I get **video duration** in **React** js...

```
const VideoList = ({ videoFile }) => {

  console.log(videoFile.duration);
  // output ==> undefined

  return (

      <div className="relative">

        <video src={videoFile} className="w-full pb-2 sm:w-32 sm:pb-0 rounded mr-2" />

        <span className="absolute bottom-1 right-3 bg-black/60 text-white rounded px-1.5">0:00</span>

      </div>
  );
}

export default VideoList;
```

Comment: I suppose `videoFile` is a string?

Answer (score 10):

You may add a `loadedmetadata` event handler to the video element. When the event is fired, the duration and dimensions of the media and tracks are known.

```
const MyVideo = ({ src }) => {
  const videoEl = useRef(null);

  const handleLoadedMetadata = () => {
    const video = videoEl.current;
    if (!video) return;
    console.log(`The video is ${video.duration} seconds long.`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <video src={src} ref={videoEl} onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadedMetadata} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) about HTML5 video element

Comment: Thank you so much... it's working... & also learned a new way of thinking about this kind of situation if it happens again.